# How to select from views bigquery?

Tags: view, google-bigquery

I want to retrieve my real time Google Analytics data from Bigquery views. Attached is my current queries:

```
select datetime(timestamp_micros(visitstarttime*1000000),"Asia/Jakarta") as ga_datetime
, device.operatingSystem as ga_os
, trafficSource.source as ga_source
, trafficSource.medium as ga_medium
,COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(CAST(fullvisitorid AS string),CAST(visitid AS string))) AS ga_session
from `43864393.ga_realtime_sessions_view_201810*` 
where _TABLE_SUFFIX between '01' and '31'
group by 1
, 2
, 3 
, 4
```

i am using Standard SQL and Bigquery returns

> Views cannot be queried through prefix

update:

I have the following views in my bigquery:

- `ga_realtime_sessions_view_20181017`
- `ga_realtime_sessions_view_20181018`
- `ga_realtime_sessions_view_20181019`
- and counting until `ga_realtime_sessions_view_20181031`

i want to select from all of those views. 
How do i resolve this?

Comment: Well it looks like selecting from `43864393.ga_realtime_sessions_view_201810*` is not valid.  What are you trying to select from?

Comment: hi @TimBiegeleisen i have updated my thread above.

Comment: When you say _"view"_, do you mean an actual BigQuery view? if you're wrapping your queries in views, then you can't use wildcards: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/views-intro#view_limitations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use wildcard character with views.If you still want to combine the results, you may want to look at UNION ALL

You can use UNION ALL in standard SQL to combine the results from multiple tables/views.

Here is an example query using UNION ALL

```
WITH subQ1 AS (SELECT column1 FROM view_1),
     subQ2 AS (SELECT column1 FROM view_2)
SELECT * FROM subQ1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM subQ2;
```

Refer to the documentation here

[UNION ALL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#union)