# Querying table views in BigQuery using wildcards with _TABLE_SUFFIX

Tags: sql, loops, google-bigquery

I try to query a large number (~140) different **table views** within Google BigQuery using *_TABLE_SUFFIX*. But this results in the following error massage:

> "Views cannot be queried through prefix."

Currently I am using this code:

```
SELECT
  tableDate, 
  `TableA.20*`.ip AS IP, 
  `TableB.20*`.city AS city, 
....
  
  CAST(s.banner AS string) AS sourcecode,

FROM
  `TableA.20*`
  CROSS JOIN UNNEST(services) AS s
  FULL OUTER JOIN `TableB.20*` USING(ip)

WHERE
_TABLE_SUFFIX IN (SELECT table_date FROM `datasetX.dates_table` AS tableDate)

AND
REGEXP_MATCH(cast(s.banner AS string), r'(?i) .....
```

Structure of "dates_table":

```
table_date 
----------    
190305
190312
190319
190326
...
[weekly dates]
```

The original data set looks like this:

[image: original data set]

As I read in the [BigQuery documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables?hl=en), wildcards are only possible to use with legacy SQL and it is **not possible to use wildcards to query >views<.**
My simple question is: **What could be an alternative way to query data from different views?** Is there another way to loop though views using wildcards?

**Possible, but not working solutions:**

The solutions suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52521822/query-failed-error-views-cannot-be-queried-through-prefix-partial-list-of-the) are unfortunately not possible in my case. I cannot change the data set, as it is a set from a external provider. Trying to expose the _TABLE_SUFFIX column, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63278795/bigquery-querying-table-suffix-in-views-with-wildcard-tables), does also not work in my case. Using UNION ALL for example, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52922047/how-to-select-from-views-bigquery), is not possible with 140 tables.

I would also be very happy to have a solution that uses BigQuery standard SQL so that I can use e.g. REGEXP_CONTAIN.

Any ideas? That would be great! Thanks a lot.

Frank

Comment: A possible solution could be to backup the tables and insert the data into a partitioned table. You can work with the partitioned tables.

Comment: hello @RaulSaucedo, thank you. What do you mean with "backup"?

Comment: make a copy of the database.

Comment: Thank you for this idea, however, due to budget-constraints it's not possible to copy and store ~250TB data :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Only (suitable) Solution**

As there is no way to iterate over table views (for whatever technical reason), it is necessary to **hard-define table view names**. Thus, I suggest to use ***UNION ALL*** and hard-code the table view names. It means much longer code and no automated/iterative process, but at least it works. ;-)

```
SELECT
  tableDate, 
  `TableA.20190305`.ip AS IP, 
  `TableB.20190305*`.city AS city, 
  CAST(s.banner AS string) AS sourcecode,

FROM
  `TableA.20*`
  CROSS JOIN UNNEST(services) AS s
  FULL OUTER JOIN `TableB.20190305` USING(ip)

UNION ALL

SELECT 
  tableDate, 
  `TableA.20190312`.ip AS IP, 
  `TableB.20190312`.city AS city, 
  CAST(s.banner AS string) AS sourcecode,

FROM
  `TableA.20*`
  CROSS JOIN UNNEST(services) AS s
  FULL OUTER JOIN `TableB.20190312` USING(ip)

UNION ALL 
<all further tables>


WHERE
REGEXP_MATCH(cast(s.banner AS string), r'(?i) .....
```